# Deep Neural Network From Scratch, accuracy stuck

Tags: python, numpy, deep-learning

I always got the same accuracy and the accuracy is badly when compared with tensorflow

First, i apologize for my bad english.

Here's the code below:

```
y_temp= []
y_temp2 = []

for i in range(len(y_train)):
    temp = ([y_train.iloc[i]])
    y_temp.append(temp)
y = np.array((y_temp), dtype=np.float128)

for i in range(len(y_test)):
    temp2= ([y_test.iloc[i]])
    y_temp2.append(temp2)
y2 = np.array((y_temp2), dtype=np.float128)


def sigmoid(self, x):
    t = t.astype(np.float128)
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-t))

def sigmoid_derivative(self, x):
    t = t.astype(np.float128)
    return sigmoid(t) * (1-sigmoid(t))

def relu(t):
    t = t.astype(np.float128)
    return np.maximum(0, t)

def relu_derivative(t):
    t = t.astype(np.float128)
    t[t <= 0] = 0
    t[t > 0] = 1
    return t


class DeepNeuralNetwork:
    def __init__(self, perceptron, x, y, hidden_layer, lr, bias):
        np.random.seed(42)
        self.hl = hidden_layer
        self.weights = {}
        self.input = x
        self.perceptron_input = self.input.shape[1]
        self.perceptron_output = 1
        self.lr = lr
        self.y = y

        # inisialisasi weight for each neuron 
        for i in range(hidden_layer): 
            self.weights[i] = np.random.rand(self.perceptron_input,perceptron) * sqrt(2.0 / self.perceptron_input)  
        self.weights[hidden_layer] = np.random.randn(perceptron, self.perceptron_output) * np.sqrt(1. / perceptron) 

        self.y = y
        self.output = np.zeros(y.shape)



    #forward propagation
    def forward_prop(self, hidden_layer):
        self.layer = {}


        self.layer[0] = relu(np.dot(self.input, self.weights[0])) 

        for i in range(hidden_layer+1): 
            if i != 0: 
                #perhitungan activation function relu
                self.layer[i] = relu(np.dot(self.layer[i-1], self.weights[i]))
            if i == hidden_layer:
                self.layer[i] = sigmoid(np.dot(self.layer[i-1], self.weights[i]))

        return self.layer[i]



    def backward_prop(self, hidden_layer):
        dW = {}
        E = {}

        #backpropagation output layer
        E[hidden_layer] = (self.y - self.output) * sigmoid_derivative(self.output)
        self.layer[hidden_layer-1] = np.multiply(E[hidden_layer], np.int64(self.layer[hidden_layer]>0))
        dW[hidden_layer] = np.dot(self.layer[hidden_layer-1].T, E[hidden_layer]) #turunan dari weight

        for i in reversed(range(hidden_layer)): 
            if i != 0:
                E[i] = np.dot(E[i+1], self.weights[i+1].T) * relu_derivative(self.layer[i])
                self.layer[i] = np.multiply(E[i], np.int64(self.layer[i]>0))
                dW[i] = np.dot(self.layer[i-1].T,E[i])
            if i == 0:
                E[0]= np.dot(E[1], self.weights[1].T) * relu_derivative(self.layer[0])
                self.layer[i] = np.multiply(E[i], np.int64(self.layer[i]>0))
                dW[0] = np.dot(self.input.T, E[0])
        for i in range(hidden_layer+1):
            self.weights[i] += self.lr * dW[i]  #lr


    def train(self, epoch):
        for i in range(epoch):
            self.output = self.forward_prop(self.hl) 
            self.backward_prop(self.hl)
            self.hitung_akurasi(self.input, self.y)


    def hitung_akurasi(self, X, y):
        predictions = []
        counter = 0

        for i in range(len(y)): #loop
            if self.output[i] >= 0.5: #if output greaterthan 0.5
                prediksi = 1 
            else:
                prediksi = 0
            predictions.append(prediksi)


            if predictions[i] == y[i]:
                counter = counter+1

        akurasi = (counter/len(y)) * 100    

        cm = confusion_matrix(predictions, y)
        true_positive = cm[1,1]
        true_negative = cm[0,0]
        false_positive = cm[0,1]
        false_negative = cm[1,0]

        print('Accuracy: '+ str(akurasi))



hl = 4
epoch = 50
lr = 0.01
nn = DeepNeuralNetwork(6, x_train_scaled, y, hl, lr, 0)
nn.train(epoch)
```

I got output like:

`Output: Accuracy: 50.00835414342936 Accuracy: 50.00835414342936 Accuracy: 50.00835414342936 Accuracy: 50.00835414342936 Accuracy: 50.00835414342936 Accuracy: 50.00835414342936 Accuracy: 50.00835414342936 Accuracy: 50.00835414342936 Accuracy: 50.00835414342936 Accuracy: 50.00835414342936 Accuracy: 50.00835414342936 Accuracy: 50.00835414342936 Accuracy: 50.00835414342936 Accuracy: 50.00835414342936 Accuracy: 50.00835414342936 Accuracy: 50.00835414342936 Accuracy: 50.00835414342936 Accuracy: 50.00835414342936 Accuracy: 50.00835414342936 Accuracy: 50.00835414342936 Accuracy: 50.00835414342936 Accuracy: 50.00835414342936 ...........................`

I always got the same accuracy until the last epoch. If i got 40% accuracy first, until last the accuracy is always 40% and and so on. I want the accuracy to vary according to the epoch it is running on.

I try to use tensorflow and i got accuracy about 70 to 79 percent. Please help me to fix my code. This code is used for my thesis in bachelor degree.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can try:

There's an issue with your backward_prop function. You're using np.int64(self.layer[hidden_layer]>0) which is incorrect for the gradient calculation. You should be using the derivative of the activation function instead.
Replace:

self.layer[hidden_layer-1] = np.multiply(E[hidden_layer], np.int64(self.layer[hidden_layer]>0))

With:

self.layer[hidden_layer-1] = np.multiply(E[hidden_layer], sigmoid_derivative(self.layer[hidden_layer]))
And replace:

And:
self.layer[i] = np.multiply(E[i], np.int64(self.layer[i]>0))

With:
self.layer[i] = np.multiply(E[i], relu_derivative(self.layer[i]))

Keep in mind that there's no guarantee that your custom model will perform as well as the TensorFlow model, as there are many factors that contribute to model performance.